# Is there a solution to bypass Captcha verification to access sites?

Tags: captcha, cloudflare

I want to login on a WordPress site. When i try to accesss to login on a WordPress site, it say me "Checking your browser before accessing", why i see the link "DDoS Protection by Cloudflare"? Additionally, a CAPTCHA is required to access this site. How to bypass Captcha verification in order to access sites? Here's the images links:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju3f7.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrhi4.png

Comment: I mean being hard to bypass is literally the point.

Comment: Use a service like 2captcha.com for this.

Answer (score 1):

Ways to bypass captcha which come to my mind:

1. Talk to guys of site or service in question if you have good reason to get exception based on IP or similar
2. Use some coding to automatically solve captcha for you. Often captcha is made so simple to be solved by some simple algorithm.
3. If none of the above works (which I think is your case), create porn site where users need to solve captchas to see the content. Make a system which automatically reroutes captchas annoying you to users who want to watch porn. If done properly, all works as charm.

PS: Actually captchas are there with reason and usually it is not nice to cheat here but I explained how it technically possible. Do not judge me for not judging others at this. SO asked me to be nice to newcomer.

PS2: Avoiding, breaking or otherwise messing up with access control security can be illegal in some jurisdictions. Especially if it caused harm to site but overloading it and thus making unavailable. For techie this may look stupid but sometime things go this way in real world.

Comment: #2. "Often captha is made so simple". If it's any good, i.e. what cloudflare uses, then it is not simple, and that is the precise intention.

Comment: I attempted to be more generic. #3 answers question if you keep reading :)

Comment: Guy who downvoted it please explain your reasons in comment.

Comment: I think there is a value in your answer of farm-solving captchas, at least that's what happens in the wild, but your point #3 does not describe it very well

Comment: Possibly you are right. Meanwhile I feel can't at moment do it better than I did.

Comment: I can finally bypass verification! I just installed Privacy Pass from Chrome Web Store on my Edge browser to bypass Captcha verification. Wanna bypass Captcha verification to access sites? Go to: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-pass/ajhmfdgkijocedmfjonnpjfojldioehi/related

Comment: Finally, I found the best answere!
Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

That is because your IP address is suspicious!
Cloudflare detects your IP address as potential bots or other malicious software.
Don't worry! usually your IP address will change after a while (24 hours or so).
In the mean time you can use another network to access the site or use a VPN service to change your IP address (a VPN extension will be the best choice in your case.)

Comment: This answer is so wrong. First, IP address is just a number, it cannot be "suspicious". Second, IP address may or may not change. For example even I had dynamic IP in my apartment in Japan, IP address was never changed, so I ran all servers behind it as it was static IP. Also this answer is wrong because decision to show Captcha to user is usually not based on IP address but on on set of different possible parameters. IP is just one of these.

Comment: >There are several common >reasons a Cloudflare-protected website displays a Captcha >to a site visitor:
>1- The visitor’s IP address demonstrated previous suspicious activity online.  Review >your client IP address for malicious activity at Project Honeypot.  If no suspicious activity >is observed from the visitor’s IP address after a two-week period, Cloudflare stops >challenging the IP address.
>2- The website owner blocked the country associated with the visitor’s client IP.
>3- The visitor’s actions activated a Web Application Firewall rule enabled by the website owner.